# ¿Es posible cambiar el nombre del proceso en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: c#, proceso

Me gustaría saber si puedo cambiar el nombre del proceso que estoy ejecutando en el momento de la ejecución.
Es decir:

```
public static void Main()
{
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName; // Aquí tendríamos el nombre original que aparece en el ensamblado
//Asignar un nombre nuevo
Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName; // Aquí tener el nombre modificado
             
}
```

Me gustaría saber si esto es posible y en caso de que sí, cómo hacerlo.

Gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [Segun la documetacion oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processname?view=net-6.0#remarks):

> La propiedad ProcessName **contiene un nombre de archivo ejecutable**,
> como Outlook, que no incluye la extensión .exe ni la ruta. Es útil
> para obtener y manipular todos los procesos que están asociados con el
> mismo archivo ejecutable.

Esto significa que la propiedad `ProcessName` no es mas que el nombre del archivo del ejecutable con el cual inicias el proceso y esto es algo que solo se puede asignar al momento de iniciar la instancia del proceso.